# Por que uma array char suporta um caractere como o 'ç' e uma variavel char não?

Tags: c, c++

Mesmo sabendo a variável char suporta somente os caracteres do ASCII, por que no seguinte código tem a saída normal quando é inserido um valor com caracteres que não fazem parte do ASCII como caracteres acentuados?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char test2[10];

    cin.get(test2, 10);

    cout << test2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

E ainda, porque se um array de char aceita a entrada desse tipo de caractere. Por que o char não aceita? Como eu posso representa esse caracteres no c++ ? Devo usar o tipo wchar_t? Já li alguma sobre o tipo em livros, mas como todos os livros eram em inglês ou foram traduzidos do inglês parece que os autores não deram muita atenção ao tipo wchar_t.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isto pouco tem a ver com C ou C++ ou outra linguagem de programação.

Internamente, o computador so conhece números. Para representar letras usa-se uma *codificação*. Cada pessoa pode fazer a sua própria codificação personalizada.

Ha varias codificações correntes.

Muitas dessas codificações usam apenas os números de `0` a `255` (ou `-128` a `127`), ou seja, são codificações para 8 bits.

Na codificação ASCII (de apenas 7 bits) não existe representação para, por exemplo, `ã`.

Quando o uso de computadores se alargou foi preciso alargar as codificações usadas para poderem representar mais de 128 caracteres.

Uma das novas codificações criadas tem o nome de ISO-8859-1. Nesta codificação o `ã` tem o código 227. Por exemplo, na codificação ISO-8859-8, o mesmo código 227 representa o caracter `ד` (Dalet).

Até aqui tudo muito bem. Todos os números codificados cabem em 8 bits.

Obviamente que ha o problema de se ter sempre de saber qual foi a codificação usada originalmente para se poder converter os números em caracteres. Este problema acontecia com frequência no principio da internet quando pessoas de países diferentes trocavam emails, cada um usando uma codificação diferente.

Para resolver este problema das codificações diferentes, então inventou-se um esquema de codificar mais de 256 caracteres numa codificação única que serve para todos os países: o Unicode.

Mas os códigos unicode são muito grandes para caberem em 8 bits. Independentemente de como se traduzam esses códigos para representação interna no computador, 8 bits nao chegam ... **logo o tipo `char` não serve para Unicode** (com representação directa, UTF-8, UTF-16, ..., little-endian, big-endian, ..., ...)

Comment: Muto boa resposta. Sempre que eu comento sobre Unicode, costumo recomendar a leitura de um artigo que se tornou uma referência na explicação - e recomendo de novo para o @augusto qualquer um com dúvida semelhante: http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29

Comment: Vi o artigo, muito bom e bem explicado. Obrigado por postar.

Comment: Só de curiosidade, para complementar: em Rust o tipo `char` ocupa 4 bytes, justo por causa do Unicode. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html - Para armazenar um byte só, temos o `i8` (signed) e `u8` (unsigned) respectivamente.